# Web Color Palette Winform

Tags: c#, color-picker

Not too sure am i being dumb. What is the web colour palette widget call? The colordialog brings up another picker which is not  what i wanted

[image: Web Color Palette]

I look though the web but most of the palette does not have the web picker.
Thanks in advance
[Edited: Maybe i should rephrase the question, how do i brought up the above color picker? i do not wish to use any 3rd party widget except those which are already available in VS]

Comment: I think i could get around with the widget "ColorListBox" located under the namespace ActiproSoftware.WinUICore. It seems to be coming from Blend.BTW is blend 3rd party or from windows?

Answer (score 3):

I hope somebody comes up with an out-of-the box .Net solution.

If not, you can write your own; this is one for starters..:

[image]

```
public partial class WebColors : Form
{
    public WebColors()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Color pick { get; set; }

    private void WebColors_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var webColors =
          Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
            .Cast<KnownColor>()
            .Where(k => k >= KnownColor.Transparent && k < KnownColor.ButtonFace)
            .Select(k => Color.FromKnownColor(k))
            .OrderBy(c => c.GetHue())
            .ThenBy(c => c.GetSaturation())
            .ThenBy(c => c.GetBrightness()).ToList();

        int cc = webColors.Count;
        int n =  (int)Math.Sqrt(cc) + 0;
        int w = ClientSize.Width / (n) - 1;
        Height = (n+1) * w + 90;
        for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = "";
            lbl.AutoSize = false;
            lbl.Size = new Size(w - 1, w - 1);
            lbl.BackColor = webColors[i];
            lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            lbl.Location = new Point(1 +  w * (i  % (n+ 1)) , w * ( i / (n+1)) );
            lbl.Click += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                pick = lbl.BackColor;
                lbl_colorName.Text = pick.Name;
            };
            Controls.Add(lbl);
        }

    }

    private void cb_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void cb_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

You can add sorting options and switch the orderby clauses..

Answer (score -1):

You can use rgb colors

```
your_object_here.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 210, 210); 
your_object_here.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255);
```

Comment: But i want the GUI that shows the different color for user to choose from during runtime.